# Android webview can't draw canvas after chrome updated to 76+

Tags: android, cordova, canvas, webview, hardware-acceleration

My webview has drawing functionality inside a canvas which was working fine. But after upgradation of Chrome it stopped drawing inside canvas. I have a work around, by setting hardware acceleration true it works perfectly, but issue is my app's memory consumption increased rapidly. Is there any solution of this problem?

I am using Cordova for cross platform.

Comment: I have the same issue. It took me a whole day for finding solution. Thanks for your work around.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know about Cordova, but I think this can also help you. I found that the key to solving the HTML5 canvas issue in Android webview is within *AndroidManifest.xml*. What did I have to do? I kept the strategy of using a hybrid (custom) webview, because as I develop in Xamarin Forms for both iOS and Android, I needed the same solution on both platforms. On Android I did:

```
// Java (or similar [laughs])
// Enable hardware acceleration using code (>= level 19)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    yourWebviewObj.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    yourWebviewObj.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}

yourSettingsObj.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
yourSettingsObj.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

```
// Xamarin for Android
// Enable hardware acceleration using code (>= level 19)
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 19)
{
    yourWebviewObj.SetLayerType (LayerType.Hardware, null);
}
else
{
    yourWebviewObj.SetLayerType (LayerType.Software, null);
}

yourWebviewObj.Settings.SetRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.High);
yourWebviewObj.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.NoCache;
```

And finally, within *AndroidManifest.xml* find for `android:handwareAccelerated="false"` and you can change the value from `false` to `true`. This tip (additionally) works for both the Java universe and Xamarin.

Had another person with the same problem at [Android WebView with layer_type_software not showing HTML5 canvas content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465334/android-webview-with-layer-type-software-not-showing-html5-canvas-content/57711517) where I also posted the same solution. Sorry if my help was not enough, but today I develop applications using Xamarin. Anyway I believe that following this path will help you.